# How can I select multiple tests on py.test?

Tags: pytest

I'm familiar with the command `py.test -k string` for select all tests that contains the `string` in their name and run it.

What I want is to select tests with more than one `string` parameter like an `OR` logical selection. For example, let's say that I have 3 tests:

- `test_should_connect`
- `test_should_execute`
- `test_should_return`

And let's say I just want to run `test_should_connect` and `test_should_return` only.
I've looked for an answer in [py.test documentation](http://pytest.org/latest/example/markers.html#using-k-expr-to-select-tests-based-on-their-name), and to do that I should use the following command:

```
py.test -k "connect or return"
```

But, this doesn't work =/

Answer (score 12):

`py.test -k "connect or return"` should work.  Are you using pytest==2.3.4? Could you paste the output from "py.test" otherwise along with the tests?

Comment: As of pytest-2.5.1 ``py.test -k "connect or return"`` does unfortunately not work because you can't use python keywords in such expressions.  ``-k "connect or retur"`` would work, though.  pytest currently defers to python for evaluating the matching expression which is where the limitation to "don't use keywords" comes from.

Answer (score 0):

`-k` should work just fine here again these days (with newer `pytest`)--if you want a full-blown regex you can also use [`pytest-regex`](https://github.com/tylerjereddy/pytest-regex) (I just released it on PyPI) and do something like this: `pytest -v --regex ".*test_(connect|return)$"`

which will run tests where the regex matches the node id, where node id looks like:

`path/to/test_module.py::TestClass::test_name[parameter_value]`

A discussion for potential inclusion in `pytest` proper is happening here, but not sure where it will land: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/11024